# Write XML from arraylist with XStream

Tags: java, class, arraylist, xstream

I have the class Alm_datos, with an arraylist, with some Employees inside:

```
public class Alm_datos  extends InputSource{

     static ArrayList<Empleado> listaEmpleados = new ArrayList<>();
```

An another class, to write the file with xml

public class Xstream {

```
Alm_datos alm = new Alm_datos();

public void xstreamSerializar() throws FileNotFoundException{

    XStream xs = new XStream();
    xs.alias("EmpleadoXS", Empleado.class);
    xs.toXML(alm.listaEmpleados , new leOutputStream("EmpleadosXS.xml"));

    }//END METODO

}//END CLASS
```

But it's not fine :S

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:369)
    at empleadosaleatorio.Xstream.xstreamSerializar(Xstream.java:18)
    at empleadosaleatorio.EmpleadosAleatorio.menu(EmpleadosAleatorio.java:150)
    at empleadosaleatorio.EmpleadosAleatorio.main(EmpleadosAleatorio.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: you have a dependency issue..are you using maven?  perhaps ur missing xmlpull  
<dependency>
    <groupId>xmlpull</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlpull</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Thanks, i added all XStream jars to my project, and works :D

Comment: welcome. i made this comment 'answer' for you to accept! Thanks @Paco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a dependency issue..are you using maven? 
perhaps  your missing xmlpull library

```
<dependency> <groupId>xmlpull</groupId> <artifactId>xmlpull</artifactId> <version>1.1.3.1</version> </dependency>
```